# ASP.MVC2.0/EF4.0 site deployment/maintenance

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-2008-r2, dac

My small team used asp.mvc 2.0/entity framework 4.0(model first approach)/Windows Server 2008r2/Sql Server 2008 r2 stack in out web site project. We've already complete developing process, and come to the web deployment stage. In this stage we are faced with the problem - ok we'll use vs2010 features for initial server/db deploy, but what we'll do in the future? Obviously some of our models can be modified after publishing in order to satisfy new conditions, and of course our server db will contains users data sets, articles etc. Is there any approach to update servers db with new db modification, without dropping db, and converting data from old instance to the new one?
Now we have found only DAC/DACPAC approach to update server db, but we don't know how to bind auto EF model generation with DAC. 
May be there is exists another solution? Is there any standard way to resolve this kind of situation? Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know if you have found a solution to this yet?

Have you tried simply generating a database based on your EF model, and using a schema comparison tool such as SQL Compare to deploy changes from the EF-generated database and your target production server?